# Remove accents on a string field in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, accent-sensitive

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM main_creditperson WHERE name="Irene Olga López"
```

This will reutrn:

```
id         name
366354     Irene Olga López
```

Is there a simple way to do this **in the query** so the result is removed of all accents?

```
id         name
366354     Irene Olga Lopez
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a  function to replace accents to a normal word.

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE main_creditperson(id int,name Nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO main_creditperson VALUES (366354,N'Irene Olga López');


ALTER TABLE main_creditperson 
MODIFY name VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4      
      COLLATE utf8mb4_bin; 

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_remove_accents;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION fn_remove_accents( textvalue VARCHAR(10000) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)

BEGIN

    SET @textvalue = textvalue;

    -- ACCENTS
    SET @withaccents = 'ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ';
    SET @withoutaccents = 'SsZzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyybf';
    SET @count = LENGTH(@withaccents);

    WHILE @count > 0 DO
        SET @textvalue = REPLACE(@textvalue, SUBSTRING(@withaccents, @count, 1), SUBSTRING(@withoutaccents, @count, 1));
        SET @count = @count - 1;
    END WHILE;

    SET @special = '!@#$%¨&*()_+=§¹²³£¢¬"`´{[^~}]<,>.:;?/°ºª+*|\\''';
    SET @count = LENGTH(@special);

    WHILE @count > 0 do
        SET @textvalue = REPLACE(@textvalue, SUBSTRING(@special, @count, 1), '');
        SET @count = @count - 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN @textvalue;

END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id,fn_remove_accents(name)  name
FROM main_creditperson 
WHERE name="Irene Olga López";

| id     | name             |
| ------ | ---------------- |
| 366354 | Irene Olga Lopez |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivjMCceSYHb6y2aYMycYC4/2)

---

[function Reference](https://gist.github.com/jgdoncel/bc20b39b8cd612c4a26dfcaf3bb14dd8)

Answer (score 0):

If the `COLLATION` is any of the `..._ci` variants, then accents are ignored when comparing.  That is, no accent-stripping code is needed.